# How can I display the HTML tag correctly

Tags: php, quoted-printable

I will read an email via PHP.
However I'm stocking at the following point.
I receive the values from the mail via class id's:

```
$Sadress_Lname = utf8_encode(quoted_printable_decode(get_content($bodyText,'<span id=3D"Sadress_Lname">','span')));
```

If the received value contains an html tag which is divided by an UTF 8 sign, it doesn't work.
Example:

```
<p>span id=3D"Sadress_Lname">Meier</=`span></p>
```

This will ouptput: Meier</= span> ...

Can someone helpme to decode it, to display just "Meyer"?

Comment: because it's not a valid html tag !!

Comment: how did you echo out the code?

Answer (score 1):

Try to remove the

> =`

on span tag

Comment: That is not possible, because it is an e-mail. The = are set automatically